# Do storage backends in Django handle deleting old static files?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, storage

I can set up a storage backend in Django and run `collectstatic` to generate all static files on my site. This works great. However, I'm wondering if Django provides any mechanism for deleting old static files which are no longer used.

With a simple file-based backend, I could simply use `rsync` with `--delete` to deploy the newest files. I'm more concerned about this when using a backend such as S3. One option would be to cycle through containers and delete old containers, but this feels wrong.

Ideally, there would be an rsync-like command I could run which would copy new files and  delete unused files for me. (Something like [Asset Sync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) for Rails.)

Alternatively, if I'm asking the wrong question, I welcome other solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is no. I've decided just to live with this for now. Coding up a solution for this seems like more effort than it's worth given how cheap storage is.